# AWS Dynamodb attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to add a dynamodb like this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.TableV2.html

How do I specify attributes ? there is a struct attribute which is listed in the documentation, but where/how do I use it ?

This is how I am creating the table:

```
var  clientLoanData =  new dynamodb.TableV2(this, "X", {
    partitionKey: {
      name: "LoanFileIngestionCustomerID",
      type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
    },
    removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
  });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.Attribute.html

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is a non-relational database. As such, you don't have to specify a structure of your documents before you add them to the table. CDK does not allow you to specify this information.

With this being said, there are *some* attributes your items are required to have so that DynamoDB can organize, partition and shard your data. These attributes include (but are not limited to) those involved in the [Primary Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey): the partition key and (optionally) the sort key.

If we look at the [`CreateTable` parameter `AttributeDefinitions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-AttributeDefinitions), it reads:

> An array of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and indexes.

Comment: so there is no way to specify it until you add the document ?

Comment: so then you define the columns in the document ? how would one do that

Comment: I would advice reading more about NoSQL databases. The DynamoDB documentation has an introduction [From SQL to NoSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.html). There's no such concept as "columns" in NoSQL databases. Each document has its own fields. Every document can have different structure as long as it contains those fields required by the primary key.

Comment: so I started reading the tutorial it talks about attributedefinition in the tutorial ...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.CreateTable.html